# DB2 - Java Driver

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

What will be best driver to connect DB2-Java? I read about db2jcc.jar, later i read in [IBM portal](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvintro.html) that this jar got deprecated. My App will be deploying to PCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation mentions that `db2jcc.jar` is deprecated, but not `db2jcc4.jar`

Driver options:

> - **db2jcc.jar** and **sqlj.zip** for JDBC 3.0 and earlier support
> - **db2jcc4.jar** and **sqlj4.zip** for JDBC 4.0 or later, and JDBC 3.0 or earlier support

Deprecated warning:

> **db2jcc.jar** and **sqlj.zip** are now deprecated.

You may use now **db2jcc4.jar** and **sqlj4.zip**.